# python selenium select from drop-down menu

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select the "CAS Number" option on [this website](http://www.strem.com/). From reading other posts, I have written several Python code using Selenium

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#selectbox > option[value='cas']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id ='selectbox']/option[@value ='cas']").click()

box = driver.find_element_by_id('selectbox')
    for option in box.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'cas':
    option.select()
```

But they all fail to select the appropriate box. So I am wondering where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First click on the `input`, then click the list item you need. Example, for `CAS Number`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.strem.com')

element = driver.find_element_by_id('selectbox_input')
element.click()

li = driver.find_element_by_id('selectbox_input_cas')
li.click()
```

Note that it is not a regular `select` tag that could be much easier operated with using [`selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=select#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select)

Comment: i see. so i need to first click open the dropdown menu before selecting the item of interest. Thank you so much for your help. The code works!

Comment: when you said that "it is not a regular select tag," are you referring to the fact that we need to first click open the select box before selecting for the item of interest? I do not know when I can use it and when I can't. Thank you.

Comment: @user3788728 yeah, it is basically a `div` with a list inside. The actual `select` is hidden and used under the hood. There is nothing wrong in using the solution in the answer. It is basically the same as you do manually in the browser.

Comment: Oh I see. It made more sense now. That's what the li stands for. My friend and I had a hard time yesterday and were researching how to use xpath on the li section. This way is easier to use and understand. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

After inspecting the DOM of that website, `<select id="selectbox" name="focus" style="display: none;">` isn't the one people see in the UI.

The actual drop-down menu is:

```
<div id="selectbox_container" class="selectbox-wrapper" style="display: none; width: 150px;">
   <ul>
      <li id="selectbox_input_product" class="selected">Product Name or Number</li>
      <li id="selectbox_input_cas">CAS Number</li>
      <li id="selectbox_input_mdl">MDL Number</li>
      <li id="selectbox_input_msds">MSDS</li>
      <li id="selectbox_input_cofa">Certificate of Analysis</li>
      <li id="selectbox_input_formula">Molecular Formula</li>
      <li id="selectbox_input_keyword">Keyword</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Hence please give the following code a try:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.strem.com/")

driver.find_element_by_id("selectbox_input").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("selectbox_input_cas").click()
```

Comment: thank you very much for your kind clarification. this code works great! do you mind explaining how I can tell what people actually see in the UI?

Comment: ummmmm... both you and the previous user gave me similar codes that work, so i hope you wouldn't mind me giving the "check" to alecxe >_<. I really appreciate all the help that you are giving me on my python journey!!!!

Comment: @user3788728: That's ok. alecxe answered one minute before me. ;(. You can still upvote me by clicking up arrow. Thanks. You can use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tool to inspect DOM and figure the structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
theMenu = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Title of Menu')
theMenu.click()
menuItem = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Title of Menu Item')
menuItem.click()
```